# how we close a div in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to close a div not hide.
I use this code to append div with id.Now i want to remove it one by one and i want remove div id

```
   function Attach_oneDiv(cls_r)
   {
   var call_id=document.getElementById('hidden_div').value;
   var r=parseInt(call_id)+1;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {

   var NewDiv=xmlhttp.responseText;
   $( "#continue_field" ).append(NewDiv);   
   document.getElementById('hidden_div').value=r;
   //document.getElementById('_AttachMore').style.display='block';
   }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.xyz.co.in/ajax.php?cls_r="+r,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

Comment: `var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);` ??

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery just call

```
$("#My_Element").remove()
```

using native javascript

```
var c = document.getElementById("My_Element");
c.parentNode.removeChild(c);
```